# Extract string between the pattern1 and pattern2 in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2012

data in a column(c1):
some_datadata1/By_User/some_other_other_data1/somedate1
some_datadata2/By_User/some_other_other_data2/somedate2
some_datadata3/By_User/some_other_other_data3/somedate3
some_datadata4/By_User/some_other_other_data4/somedate4

Output required:
some_other_data1
some_other_data2
some_other_data3
some_other_data4

I am looking for a query to do so

I tried following but did not work:

```
select col1,
       substring(col1,charindex('By User/',col1)+len('By User/'),
         charindex('/',col1)-charindex('By User/',col1)-len('By User/')) 
from tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably better to split strings in your application code.

However, if you have no choice, you can use `LEFT` since pattern1 is the first one on the left of the string:

```
Select col1, LEFT(col1, CHARINDEX('By_User/',col1) -2)
From (values ('some_datadata1/By_User/some_other_other_data1/somedate1')
    , ('some_datadata2/By_User/some_other_other_data2/somedate2')
    , ('some_datadata3/By_User/some_other_other_data3/somedate3')
    , ('some_datadata4/By_User/some_other_other_data4/somedate4')) as string(col1)
```

If you want pattern 3, the second CHARINDEX need to start looking for / after the position of the second pattern:

```
Select col1, left(col1, CHARINDEX('By_User/',col1) -2)
    , SUBSTRING(col1, CHARINDEX('By_User/',col1) + len('By_User/'), 
        CHARINDEX('/',col1, CHARINDEX('By_User/',col1) + len('By_User/')) 
        - CHARINDEX('By_User/',col1) - len('By_User/')
        )
From (values ('some_datadata1/By_User/some_other_other_data1/somedate1')
    , ('some_datadata2/By_User/some_other_other_data2/somedate2')
    , ('some_datadata3/By_User/some_other_other_data3/somedate3')
    , ('some_datadata4/By_User/some_other_other_data4/somedate4')) as string(col1)
```

Comment: Solution  :  select SUBSTRING(col,
                            CHARINDEX('/', col , CHARINDEX('By',col))+1, 
                            CHARINDEX('/', col ,CHARINDEX('/', col , CHARINDEX('By',col))+1)-1 - CHARINDEX('/', col , CHARINDEX('By',col)))
 from tablename where CHARINDEX('/', col ,CHARINDEX('/', col , CHARINDEX('By',col))+1) - CHARINDEX('/', col , CHARINDEX('By',col))>0